# DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (TBODY). PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to use [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) second time in other PHP Page but I'm stock in this error,

> DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (TBODY).

What did i do wrong? i tried this code with my first PHP Page and its working fine.

Here is my Code for Table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="page-header">
                      <h1 id="tables">Admin's Accounts</h1>
                  </div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus-circle zmdi-hc-2x"></i></button>
                      <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>#</th>
                                  <th>Name</th>
                                  <th>Contact</th>
                                  <th>Email Address</th>
                                  <th>Position</th>
                                  <th>Option</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody id="admin">
                                  <?php
                            //set up mysql connection
                            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
                            //select database
                            mysql_select_db("brm_dbs") or die(mysql_error());
                                    //select all records form tblmember table
                                    $query = 'SELECT uid,name,contact,email,position FROM admin ORDER BY created_at DESC';
                                    //execute the query using mysql_query
                                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                                   //then using while loop, it will display all the records inside the table
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo ' <tr> ';
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['uid'];
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['name'];
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['contact'];
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['email'];
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['position'];
                                        echo '<td>';
                                        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'.$row['uid'].'"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus-circle zmdi-hc-2x"></i></button>';
                                    }
                              ?>
                          </tbody>
                  </table> 
              </div>
          </div>
          </table>
```

And I'm using this for JQUERY

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#admin').DataTable( {
                 "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]]
             });
         } );
    </script>
```

Comment: I think ID attribute in tbody is problem. I think its not allowed in tbody element or DataTables don't recognize this (dirty) tag.

Comment: if its not allowed why it work for my first page?

Comment: you are sure its a right way? The DataTables plugin should be loaded on selector placed in table tag not inside the body.

Comment: look at examples in documenation, i don't see something like your code. https://www.datatables.net/examples/index

Comment: i tried it and nothings work, no error but no pagination and filter

Comment: ok well ... you have 6x TH, 7x TD ? this is not compatible and may cause this bad behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edit my Code for Table, I have **Syntax Error** **6TH** but **7TD** and only removed the last TD in `echo` and its working fine now.

Answer (score 6):

I got Error: Non-table node initialization due to have same "ID" for another element in DOM

```
<table id="allProducts" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
```

and same id in nav menu

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="allProducts" ><i class="fa fa-star"></i> All Products</a>
```

due to this same id repetition i got error ...:)
keep coding have a great time

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/2), the error occurs in either one of these cases.

Take for example this div and table

```
<div id="demo" class="display">
    <table class="display">...</table>
</div>
```

If you try to initialise DataTables on `#demo`

```
$('#demo').dataTable()
```

You'll get an error as `#demo` is not the table element.

If you try to initialise on `.display`

```
$('.display').dataTable();
```

You'll get an error as `.display` is too vague, meaning there's more than one element having that class, and DataTables expect a unique element.

Conclusion :

1. Make sure you're initialising DT on the correct node element
2. Make sure DT's element's class/ID are unique.

Comment: Good answer, also make sure you do not have 2 IDs with the same name.  This should be avoided anyway as IDs should be unique but it is another way to cause this issue